# Merging 3 lists (or more)

Tags: list, currency, merging-data

I have 2 lists/arrays of strings

- a list of currencies:

  `String [] currencies = {EUR, USD, CAD, etc};`
- a list of time periods:

  `String [] periods = {"T","O","SN", "1M","1Y","1W", "2M","3M","4M","5M","6M","7M","8M","9M","10M","11M", ...};`
- a list of suffixes:

  `String list suffixes = {"D", "FSR", "ND", etc};`

I want to merge them lists. I need to define a mapping because I don't want to merge all to all (more like some to some).

For example:

> EUR can be combined with "1M" and "2M" from periods, and with "D" and
>   "FSR" from suffixes.
>
> USD can be combined with "1M", "3M" and "4M" from
>   periods, and with "ND" from suffixes.

How would you suggest I do this mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using a dictionary that supports collisions. That is what they are built for.

Comment: tx! that's what I'm using at the moment. I'm curious if there are other better ways.

Comment: @Adrian I'm sure you could get tricky with other existing data structures. I doubt there are any that are going to make it overly easier or increase performance.

Comment: @Adrian Is this list predefined and immutable? Also, is the number of items involved much larger than your example demonstrates?

Comment: The lists are immutable and their size is around 100. But I'm willing to change the design and make them mutable if a nice solution requires that :)

Comment: @Adrian The reason I asked is because if the average length of a list at a given key, is somewhat large, then it would probably improved performance to use a dictionary that maps to BSTs. But if the number of collisions at a key is relatively small then I don't see a lot of gain in performance.